# get_result() Doesn't Work even mysqlnd is enabled

Tags: php, mysql, mysqlnd

It might be a duplication of many questions however i dont seem to get my answer from any of the questions present.I am using `multi domain linux hosting` provided by hostgator.I tried to use `mysqli_stmt_get_result()` but it throws me an error stating as an`undefined method`.I contacted the hostgator admin panel and they enabled the mysqlnd extension for me.I do see the mysqlnd extension enabled in   phpinfo of my website.However i still see the same error.

```
$mysqlnd = function_exists('mysqli_stmt_get_result');

if ($mysqlnd) {
    echo 'mysqlnd enabled!';
}
else
   var_dump("nope");
```

I tried to check if it is enabled or not , it says `nope` but i do see mysqlnd as enabled in my `phpinfo`.

What is the problem and how can i solve this one ? Plus using with any other method is not an option because i have already coded the whole project using `mysqli_stmt_get_result()`.

Update:

[image: Mysqli]

[image: mysqlnd]

Query:

```
 $stmt=$this->link->prepare("SELECT `Session_Data`,`ip_address` FROM Session WHERE `Session_Id` = ? AND `Session_Expires` > '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'");

        $stmt->bind_param("s",$id);
        $stmt->execute();
         $res=$stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: Need to show the actual query and `get_result` code.

Comment: Your descriptions are kind of vague and your sample code only tests for a a function that does not exist at all. Can you see `mysqlnd` in the *Client API library version* row of the *mysqli* table?  Can you see `mysqli` in the *API Extensions* row of the *mysqlnd* table?

Comment: @AbraCadaver wait i will update my post

Comment: Ok, my comment wasn't so wrong. http://php.net/manual/de/mysqlnd.plugin.php `mysqlnd` is just a plugin to work between MySQLi or PDO and MySQL. You still need either one of those extension.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález see the question.I have updated the question with the relevent things you asked for

Comment: Uh, eh http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mysqli_fetch_all&lang=de&scope=404quickref The function you are looking for doesn't exist at all.

Comment: The mysqlnd driver appears to be on the server but I'd say it isn't configured to work with any extension.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález how would i achieve that?

Comment: Just seen your last edit: you want `mysqli_stmt_get_result`!

Comment: @CharlotteDunois updated my question anyways

Comment: Perhaps you need be more specific when you talk to Hostgator support. You have to explain you want to use `mysqli_stmt_get_result` so you need the `mysqlnd` driver configured to work with the `mysqli` extension.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois fine?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález sure i will ask them to do so.Let me see what they say

Comment: @CharlotteDunois http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To make this thing work, Enable `nd_mysqli` in php extensions and disable `mysqli`. This will work like charm!

Comment: how did you do that through cpanel?

Comment: @user2782001 Cpanel->Select PHP version(This might be under software tab)->You will see modules there.You can check uncheck any module you want to,as well as you can change your php version.Hope, this might help.

Comment: Is there a way to enable it and keep mysqli active aswell?

Comment: i tried doing that but cpanel doesn't allow it and `nd_mysqli` is the same as `mysqli`, i have kept it active while unchecking `mysqli` , till this day i have not faced any thing that worked on `mysqli` and not on `nd_mysqli`.

Comment: I did this after fiddling around but for some reason, although the errors have gone, no database results seem to be returning :/ PHP 7.0 / 7.1

Comment: Wow what an answer. superb answer same my lot of time to debug into server

Comment: @CodeUK debug your code , might be some logical error.

Comment: @BOTJr. I upgraded my server to PHP 7.4 and it broke my queries.  After relentless searching all day and all night with answers stating to use another function or functions; that didn't seem to work in my situation I find this and it worked wonders!!  Thank you good sir! +1

Comment: In my case, i had to uncheck "mysqli" first before i could enable "nd_mysqli"

Answer (score 3):

Go to Cpanel ->PHP version under software section and change the options as below enable nd_mysqli
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes It worked with nd_mysqli option selected. Thanks @BOTJr. It also shows 'nd_mysqli skipped as conflicting' as an warning so no need to worry just disable mysqlnd, mysqli and then enable again nd_mysqli option. It will work fine.

Comment: If you want to improve an answer edit that or make your answer more clear by formatting properly

Comment: You do not need to disable `mysqlnd` in order to enable `nd_mysqli`.  You just have to disable `mysqli`.